# pandas DataFrame isin and following row

Tags: python, pandas

For a given DataFrame, sorted by `b` and index reset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': list('abcdef'), 
                   'b': [0, 2, 7, 3, 9, 15]} 
                 ).sort_values('b').reset_index(drop=True)
   a   b
0  a   0
1  b   2
2  d   3
3  c   7
4  e   9
5  f  15
```

and a list, `v`

```
v = list('adf')
```

I would like to pull out just the rows in `v` *and* the following row (if there is one), similar to `grep -A1`:

```
   a   b
0  a   0
1  b   2
2  d   3
3  c   7
5  f  15
```

I can do this by concatenating the index from `isin` and the index from `isin` plus one, like so:

```
df[df.index.isin(
    np.concatenate(
        (df[df['a'].isin(v)].index, 
         df[df['a'].isin(v)].index + 1)))]
```

But this is long and not too easy to understand. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine the `isin` condition and the [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) (next row) to create the boolean you needed:

```
df[df.a.isin(v).pipe(lambda x: x | x.shift())]

#   a   b
#0  a   0
#1  b   2
#2  d   3
#3  c   7
#5  f  15
```

Comment: Nice answer: to note, this is functionally equivalent to `x = df.a.isin(v); x | x.shift()`. `pipe` is here just for convenience.

Comment: So what is `x | x.shift()` doing here? Is this `x OR x.shift()`? @jpp

Comment: Yes. `x` is a Boolean series, `|` means vectorised "or".